# How can I set a JBOSS data source to an Oracle database use a different schema to the one used for authentication

Tags: oracle, jboss, datasource

I have a Java webapp (WAR) that is to be run in JBOSS.

That webapp is to create connections to an Oracle database using a username/password for a user that is given read-only permissions.

The webapp queries tables belonging to a different schema. I do this by qualifying each table name in my SQL queries.

However, I would like to parameterise this in my datasource, since the schema names can be different in different environments.

Is there a way to define a JBOSS data source which logs in as User A for each connection, but uses Schema B for all queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the `new-connection-sql` or `check-valid-connection-sql` [datasource properties](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html) to execute `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=yourschema`, which will change the default schema for each connection.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is to create synonyms in Oracle for your User A to access tables in schema owned by User B. This way you can even grant specific privileges to user A to select, update, insert on tables owned by the other UserB.